# How to correctly install templates:tabs?

Tags: meteor

I'm a beginner on the amazing world of Meteor. Just a excuse, in case it's a really easy fix that I managed to miss.
I installed  [templates:tabs](https://atmospherejs.com/templates/tabs) using the given command `meteor add templates:tabs`.

But, after following the basic usage present on the install page, meteor keep spitting `ReferenceError: ReactiveTabs is not defined` whenever I try to run the server.

I have a navbar.coffee (I know, it's a dumb name)

```
ReactiveTabs.createInterface
    template: 'basicTabs'

Template.navbar.helpers
    tabs: ->
        return 
        [
            { name:'Home', slug:'home' }
            { name:'Membros', slug:'users' }
            { name:'Votar', slug:'voting' }
            { name:'Leaderboard', slug:'leaderboard'}
            { name:'Login', slug:'login' }
        ]
```

And, of course, a navbar.html

```
<template name="Navbar">
    {{#basicTabs name="" tabs=tabs}}
        {{#tabContent slug="home"}}
            {{>Home}}
        {{/tabContent}}

        {{#tabContent slug="users"}}
            {{>Users}}
        {{/tabContent}}

        {{#tabContent slug="voting"}}
            {{>Voting}}
        {{/tabContent}}

        {{#tabContent slug="leaderboard"}}
            {{>Leaderboard}}
        {{/tabContent}}

        {{#tabContent slug="login"}}
            {{>Login}}
        {{/tabContent}}
    {{/basicTabs}}
</template>
```

The full trace is as follows:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20150523-14:29:17.275(-3)? (STDERR)          
W20150523-14:29:17.276(-3)? (STDERR) /home/vitorrangel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150523-14:29:17.276(-3)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150523-14:29:17.276(-3)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: ReactiveTabs is not defined
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR)     at ./navbar.coffee:1:1
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR)     at ./navbar.coffee:1:1
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR)     at /home/vitorrangel/Workspace/estrela/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/vitorrangel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150523-14:29:17.277(-3)? (STDERR)     at /home/vitorrangel/Workspace/estrela/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

So, I guess there's something I'm missing. Maybe there's something else to install, maybe it's a deprecated package (It seems active on github, at least). But I can't catch whatever I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the 'ReactiveTabs` component is only available for use on client side code.

You can fix it by moving your client side code into the `/client` directory (you would have to create it if you don't make it)

Or you could move the code into an `if(Meteor.isClient) {` block

```
if Meteor.isClient
    ReactiveTabs.createInterface
        template: 'basicTabs'
```

There's a bit more information on how to structure your code and split it between the client and server on the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) if you want more details on it